# GPS example problem

Tags: android, gps

I am having problems with the GPS LocationListener. I don't think it's working in my emulator at all. I followed exactly what the example in this link http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/ and it still won't work. I tried telnetting it and typing geo fix 15 10, and shortly after Logcat shows "Build fingerprint", the emulator resets by itself and Logcat says "Exit zygote because system server (69) has terminated"

Comment: are you testing gps on emulator . Test it on Device.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't have an android device to test it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  test your location-based features by mocking location data in the Android emulator. You can do this :
 **using Eclipse, DDMS**.

**Using Eclipse**

Select **Window > Show View > Other > Emulator Control.**

In the Emulator Control panel, enter GPS coordinates.Then test GPS.

For more details: see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#MockData)

Comment: actually, I got the error fixed. Turns out only emulators with API levels 8 and below work.

Comment: It now works fine, i just can't post my answer now because I still have to wait for 8 hours.